# Decrypting Caeser Cipher in Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a decrypt script for a Caeser cipher script to encrypt but can't get it to work. This is my encryption script:

```
def encrypt(text,s): 

    result = "" 

    # traverse text 
    for i in range(len(text)): 
        char = text[i] 

        # Encrypt uppercase characters 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65) 

        # Encrypt lowercase characters 
        else: 
            result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97) 
            
    return result 
#def decrypt(ciphertext, s):
   

text = "0123456789"
s = 4
Cipher=encrypt(text,s)

print("Text : " + text)
print ("Shift : " + str(s))
print ("Cipher: " + encrypt(text,s))
```

I need help with creating a decrypt script the same way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code of mine for a function used to decrypt a ceaser cipher. The approach used when the shift is not known is simply to get every possible value, then pick the one with more then half the decoded words being in the English dictionary. For non alphabetic characters, there is a placeholder character used.

There are some extra parts required, such as the dictionary or extra functions / lists so I will include them in the below links.

A note, it does only work for on lowercase letters however, I do hope it will help you to understand the logic a bit better.

```py
def Decode(message, shift=-1):
    """
    Decodes a message from a caesar cipher

    Params:
     - message (str) : Message to decode
    Optional Params:
     - shift (int) : If shift is known

    Returns:
     - decodedMessage (str) : The decoded message
    """
    decodedMessage = ''
    message = message.lower() # lowercase is easier to work with

    # If the shift is known it is simple to decode
    if shift != -1:
        for letterIndex in range(len(message)):
            if message[letterIndex] in [' ', '!', '?', '.', '-', ',', '_']:
                decodedMessage += message[letterIndex]
            else:
                try:
                    index = ALPHABET.index(message[letterIndex]) - shift

                    # If the index is smaller then ALPHABET, handle it
                    while index < 0:
                        index += len(ALPHABET)

                    decodedMessage += ALPHABET[index]
                except Exception as e:
                    print("A problem occured:", e)
                    decodedMessage += '?'

        return decodedMessage
    else: #If shift is not known, figure it out thru brute force
        data = read_json('words_dictionary')
        for i in range(len(ALPHABET)):
            decodedMessage = Decode(message, i+1)
            wordList = decodedMessage.split(" ")
            try:
                # Loop over words counting english words
                count = 0
                for word in wordList:
                    if word in data.keys():
                        count += 1

                    # More accurate this way compared to only one word checks
                    if count > len(wordList) / 2:
                        return decodedMessage
            except KeyError:
                continue
```

Full code [here](https://mystb.in/RpgHelmetOperated.python)

Word dictionary [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/baof2cpz9bs3ib1/words_dictionary.json/file)

Comment: let me try this with the rest of my script but thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you work exclusively with **alphabetic words** (this rules out your example), then I can suggest something. This is useful in order to understand a little bit what is happening in the process.

In order to use it with alphanumeric words (or even sentences), you need to adapt it, taking into account the representation of each character.

First, let me define two auxiliary functions to encrypt a single alphabet letter:

```py
def _encrypt_uppercase(char, s):
    return chr((ord(char) + s - 65) % 26 + 65) 

def _encrypt_lowercase(char, s):
    return chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
```

Then, I define the corresponding functions to *decrypt* the character:

```py
def _decrypt_uppercase(char, s):
    return chr((ord(char) + (26 - s) - 65) % 26 + 65) 

def _decrypt_lowercase(char, s):
    return chr((ord(char) + (26 - s) - 97) % 26 + 97)
```

Finally, the encryption and decryption functions simply make use of the previous.

Encrypt:

```py
def encrypt(text, s): 
    result = "" 
    # Traverse text 
    for i in range(len(text)): 
        char = text[i] 

        # Encrypt uppercase characters 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += _encrypt_uppercase(char, s)
        # Encrypt lowercase characters 
        else: 
            result += _encrypt_lowercase(char, s)
    return result
```

Decryption:

```py
def decrypt(ciphertext, s):
    result = "" 
    # Traverse text 
    for i in range(len(ciphertext)): 
        char = ciphertext[i] 

        # Encrypt uppercase characters 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += _decrypt_uppercase(char, s)
        # Encrypt lowercase characters 
        else: 
            result += _decrypt_lowercase(char, s)
    return result
```

If we define the main function as:

```py
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = sys.argv[1]
    s = int(sys.argv[2])
    cipher = encrypt(text, s)

    print("Text : " + text)
    print("Shift : " + str(s))
    print("Cipher: " + cipher)
    print("Decrypt: " + decrypt(cipher, s))
```

Then we get the following:

```bash
$ python caesar2.py INcreDiBLe 4
Text : INcreDiBLe
Shift : 4
Cipher: MRgviHmFPi
Decrypt: INcreDiBLe
```